# Зацикливается scanner.nextInt

Tags: java, scanner

Не могу понять почему зацикливается scanner.nextInt в этом куске кода:

```
public int inputSize() {

        int value;

        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Введите размер таблицы от " + LEFT_BOUND + " до " + RIGHT_BOUND + ": ");

            try {
                value = scanner.nextInt();
                if (сheckInputValue(value)) {
                    return value;
                }
            }catch (InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("Введите корректное значение от " + LEFT_BOUND + " до " + RIGHT_BOUND + "! ");
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean сheckInputValue(int value) {
        try {
            //this.size = Integer.parseInt(value);
            return value <= RIGHT_BOUND && value >= LEFT_BOUND;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: У тебя сheckInputValue возвращает boolean. А функция inputSize возвращает int. Не смущает это?

Comment: Ничего не зацикливается. Возможно, вы перепутали RIGHT_BOUND и LEFT_BOUND при инициализации

Comment: @Blacit, а это должно смущать?

Comment: Все у вас нормально с кодом